# How do you tag fields of embedded structs which you cannot modify?

Tags: go, tags

Suppose there is an external library `libA` who declares `NotMyType`.

```
type NotMyType struct {
  NotMyField string
}
```

And you would like to embed it with one of your own types, which you use with an ORM, which uses the tags to adjust column properties.

```
type MyType struct {
  SomeData0 string  `orm:"nullable"`
  SomeData1 string  `orm:"nullable"`
  libA.NotMyType
}
```

For example, columns `MyType.SomeData0` and `MyType.SomeData1` are NULLABLE.

Is it possible to tag `NotMyField` with `orm:"nullable"` without modifying `NotMyType`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT: wrong answer, my bad**

Okep i think i got it. I have never used reflect before so maybe i'm wrong. But :

Take a look at what I just do :

> https://play.golang.org/p/U0uyomL-It

I have a struct

```
type User struct {
    name string
    age  int
}
```

With no tag.

I get the field with

```
field, ok := reflect.TypeOf(user).Elem().FieldByName("name")
if !ok {
    panic("Field not found")
}
```

And i set a new tag with

```
//setStructTag(&field)

func setStructTag(f *reflect.StructField) {
    f.Tag = "`json:name-field`"
}
```

Hope my researche will help you :)

Comment: Good ol' reflection.

Answer (score 0):

Go is introspective.
It has introspection (e.g. find-class allows to look at existing classes) but no intercession (e.g. ensure-class creates/modifies a class at runtime).

So you can't.

Comment: The conclusion is totally correct, you cannot modify existing tags. But your argumentation is wrong. Types can be created at runtime, see e.g. https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#StructOf (albeit a bit limited) and objects can be created from such types. You even can create function types during runtime.

Comment: Very interesting thank you :)  Yes it is a bit limited, but it exists and I ditn't know.